# Group and sum elements that are the same within a vector

Tags: matlab, math, octave, vectorization

Let's say I have a vector that looks as so (the numbers will always be > 0)...

```
[1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

I need a vectorized implementation that sums the numbers together and uses the original number as the index to store the number. So if I run it I would get...

```
% step 1
[1+1+1, 2+2, 3, 4+4]

% step 2
[3, 4, 3, 8]
```

I have already implemented this using for loops, but I feel like there is a vectorized way to achieve this. I am still quite new at vectorizing functions so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
v = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3];
result = accumarray(v(:), v(:)).'

result =

     3     4     3     8
```

Answer (score 2):

Other approaches:

- Using [`histcounts`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html):

  ```
  x = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3];
  u = unique(x);
  result = u.*histcounts(x, [u inf]);
  ```
- Using [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (may be more memory-intensive):

  ```
  x = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3];
  u = unique(x);
  result = u .* sum(bsxfun(@eq, x(:), u(:).' ), 1);
  ```

Comment: If the range is small and the number large then the histcounts is a reasonable approach and secondly any zeros are not a drama.